# TimePicker em formato 24h

Tags: android, timepicker

Estou pensando em usar TimePicker  em meu app de noticaçoes e para determinar o horario das notificaçoes estou usando calender porem o horario do TimePicker e de 0 a 12 am e 0 a 12 pm e o do calender do ciclo de 24 h se alguem conseguir pensar ne uma soluçao para isso

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O [TimePicker](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TimePicker) pode apresentar o valor tanto no formato 24h como em AM/PM.

O formato é definido recorrendo ao método [setIs24HourView()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TimePicker.html#setIs24HourView(java.lang.Boolean)).

Para definir o formato em 24h use-o passando `true`:

```
timePicker.setIs24HourView(true);
```

Comment: Perfeito obrigado